# Objective-C timer for completion block

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a function that takes a completion block. However it is possible for an error to occur and the completion block will never get called. I would like to have a timeout timer to handle if the completion block doesn't get called in time, so I can still continue and do something else.

```
void(^completeHandler)(void) = ^
{
    NSLog(@"Complete");
};

//Timer here to check if completeHandler will ever get called in a specific amount of time

[self complete:completeHandler];
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to either add an error parameter to the completion block and call it even if an error occured, or add another completion handler specifically for handling errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### As [FreeNickname says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36434935/objective-c-timer-for-completion-block#comment60484617_36434935), you're probably approaching this problem from the wrong direction.

Waiting for a completion block to return pretty much defeats the purpose of using a completion block in the first place!

Rather than using a timer to check if the completion has been called, you should just add an error and/or success argument to the completion block.

**For example:**

```
-(void) doSomethingWithCompletion:(void(^)(BOOL success, NSError* error))completion {

    // do something asynchronous

    {
        { // if success
            completion(YES, nil);
        }

        { // if fail
            NSError* error = ...
            completion(NO, error);
        }
    }
}

...


[self doSomethingWithCompletion:^(BOOL success, NSError* error) {

    if (success) { // success
        // do some success stuff
    } else { // fail
        // do some failure stuff
    }
}];
```

If you're dealing with a request where you want to impose a timeout yourself, you can always use a `dispatch_after` to schedule the completion block to fire with an unsuccessful argument - and wrap it in another block to ensure it can only get called once. For example:

```
-(void) doSomethingWithCompletion:(void(^)(BOOL success, NSError* error))completion {

    __block BOOL called = NO;

    void(^completionBlock)(BOOL success, NSError* error) = ^(BOOL success, NSError* error){
        if (!called) {
            completion(success, error);
            called = YES;
        }
    };


    // do something asynchronous

    {
        { // if success
            completionBlock(YES, nil);
        }

        { // if fail
            NSError* error = ...
            completionBlock(NO, error);
        }
    }

    // your timeout
    dispatch_time_t time =  dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(5.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC));
    dispatch_after(time, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        completionBlock(NO, nil);
    });

}
```